# Why some emojis are not converted back into their representation?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

I am working on emoji detection module. For some emojis I am observing weird behavior that is after converting them to utf-8 encoding they are not converted back to their original representation form. I need their exact colored representation to be send as API response instead of sending unicode escaped string. Any leads?

```
In [1]: x = "example1:  and example2:  and example3: " 

In [2]: x.encode('utf8')                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[2]: b'example1: \xf0\x9f\xa4\xad and example2: \xf0\x9f\x98\x81 and example3: \xf0\x9f\xa5\xba'

In [3]: x.encode('utf8').decode('utf8')                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[3]: 'example1: \U0001f92d and example2:  and example3: \U0001f97a'

In [4]: print( x.encode('utf8').decode('utf8')  )                                                                                                                                                                                 
*example1:  and example2:  and example3: *
```

[Link Emoji used in example](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f92b)

Update 1:
By this example it must be much clearer to explain. Here, two emojis are rendered when I have send unicode escape string, but 3rd exampled failed to convert exact emoji, what to do in such case?

[image: API View Code]
[image: API Response using Postman]

Comment: `x.encode('utf8').decode('utf8')==x` is `True`. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @DYZ I know that they are same thing but I want to store it in its emoji form not in unicode escape sequence.

Comment: The string contains the same data in both cases.  You are not "storing the unicode escape sequence" you are *displaying* a Unicode escape sequence for the single, correct code point in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'\U0001f92d' == ''` is `True`.  It is an escape code but is still the same character...Two ways of display/entry.  The former is the `repr()` of the string, printing calls `str()`.  Example:

```
>>> s = ''
>>> print(repr(s))
'\U0001f92d'
>>> print(str())

>>> s
'\U0001f92d'
>>> print(s)
```

When Python generates the repr() it uses an escape code representation if it thinks the display can't handle the character.  The content of the string is still the same...the Unicode code point.

It's a debug feature.  For example, is the white space spaces or tabs?  The `repr()` of the string makes it clear by using `\t` as an escape code.

```
>>> s = 'a\tb'
>>> print(s)
a       b
>>> s
'a\tb'
```

As to why an escape code is used for one emoji and not another, it depends on the version of Unicode supported by the version of Python used.

Pyton 3.8 uses Unicode 9.0, and one of your emoji isn't defined at that version level:

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.unidata_version
'9.0.0'
>>> ud.name('')
'GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES'
>>> ud.name('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: no such name
```

Comment: I know they are both same thing and equal. Question is why some emojis are displayed in   format and some are represented as unicode escape. Why not follow same identical behavior for all?

Comment: @Osama The `unicodedata` module provides information on a code point.  I'm using Python 3.8.2 and it support Unicode 9.0.  It doesn't not have a name for  in that database, so it is probably a new Unicode character.  Python due to its database thinks it is an undefined character so uses the escape code for debug display.

Comment: I have added some images to show how these emojis are not rendered in my API response. I have got your point, any solution to it?

Comment: It's a rendering problem, not a Python problem.  Complain to the IDE vendor.  U+1F97A was defined in [Unicode 11.0](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-11.0/U110-1F900.pdf).  Python and the terminal used for rendering, and the font need to support that level of the standard for it to display correctly.

Comment: @Osama Also note that Python is storing/encoding/decoding the code point correctly, even if it doesn't know what the code point represents.  It's purely a rendering issue.